# Does h5py support arbitrary nested compound datatypes?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm having trouble reading a dataset that I've created with the C++ HDF5 api, which I've asked about already [on the support list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/WLQlEr-VDtk).

I'm trying to replicate the problem by creating the same structure using `h5py`, and now I've run into a new problem: the library seems to replace the deeper nested information with information of type `H5T_OPAQUE`.

I'm building the structure with a recursive function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import copy

# arbitrary leaf type
leaf = np.dtype([('v1', 'f8'), ('v2', 'i')])
# we want to store arbitrary length array of these...
leafs = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=leaf)

# recursive calls to nest leafs in compound datatype
def nest(level=0, do_vl=False):
    # for zeroth level just return a leaf
    if level == 0:
        return np.array( [(3.4, 1), (3.2, 9)], dtype=leaf), leafs    
    # otherwise, recursively nest the data
    subdat, subtype = nest(level - 1, do_vl)    
    # optionally make the subnodes variable length
    if do_vl:
        subdat = np.array([copy.deepcopy(subdat) for i in range(2)],
                          dtype=subtype)
        subtype = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=subtype)    
    # define the nodes to be compound datatypes which include subnodes
    nodetype = np.dtype([('l', 'i'), ('x', subtype)])
    node = (level, subdat)
    return node, nodetype

# === Create the file and the data here ===
f = h5py.File('pytest.h5','w')

l1d, l1t = nest(8, True) # <--- WHEN THIS IS `True` I GET OPAQUE DATATYPES

l1_ds = f.create_dataset('entries', (1,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=l1t)
l1_ds[0] = l1d
f.close()
```

If I replace the function call on the forth-to-last line with `nest(<any number>, False)` I get exactly what I'd expect (nested compound datatypes). When I turn this to `nest(<any number>, True)` I get a structure that looks like this:

```
HDF5 "pytest.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "entries" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_STD_I32LE "l";
         H5T_VLEN { H5T_OPAQUE {
            OPAQUE_TAG "PYTHON:OBJECT";
         }} "x";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
      DATA {
      (0): {
            1,
            (08:c9:74:00:01:00:00:00, 08:c4:74:00:01:00:00:00)
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

And then when I try to read back the same information I get:

```
TypeError: Unable to convert between src and dst data types (No appropriate function for conversion path)
```

I'm a bit surprised that the nesting of data types doesn't seem to work to arbitrary order, but maybe I'm overlooking something. Is this *supposed* to work?

Comment: It is *supposed* to work, but I'm pretty sure [this is the same bug](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/623).

Comment: @Yossarian, indeed, bug report references this post.